# When to use inferred type vs explicit types in swift?

Tags: swift

Taking a look at Swift and I was wondering people's opinions on when to take advantage of inferred types? Coming from Obj-C/C I'm used to doing types all the time so that's currently how I'm writing my Swift code but there must be some reasons to use type inference? I've seen this answer, [When to exploit type inference in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463870/when-to-exploit-type-inference-in-haskell) but it's about Haskell.

Thanks!

Comment: Best practice question is very legit in daily programming.  Please don't close a ticket just because it can be an opinion, because a set of criteria can be established over time and it will no longer be opinion based after that.

Comment: @Boon He is specifically asking for opinions. How could it not be primarily opinion-based?

Answer (score 4):

My initial gut tells me that anytime you immediately or shortly declare the value of the variable it's probably preferable to allow type inference to kick in.  As a more general rule, I'd say anytime things are made more readable (subjective I know) go for it.

Things like the below I believe greatly improve from type inference.

```
let hello = "Hello"
```

vs

```
let hello: String = "Hello"
```

and a much better example:

```
let add = {
    (a1: Int, a2: Int) -> Int in
        return a1 + a2
}
```

vs

```
let add: (Int, Int) -> Int = {
    (a1: Int, a2: Int) -> Int in
        return a1 + a2
}
```

Comment: I'm skeptical of this practise, just as I would be using `auto` in C++.  If the programmer doesn't know what the type is then how does he know how to use it?  If it's to save typing then the programmer should take up another career.

Comment: Saving typing isn't the point but to improve readability.  I'd argue that not realizing that hello in my example is a string is probably a bigger problem than needing more explicit declaration.  It's ultimately a personal choice, but that's my general guideline.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. There are times where it is just painfully obvious what the data type should be. No need to be overly specific when you don't *need* to.